# Posting to Capsule CRM and an "AJAX Proxy"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, proxy

I am trying to post a Capsule CRM page using http://support.capsulecrm.com/customer/portal/articles/1639817-website-contact-form-integration which I can get working quite easily. However, I wanted to post this using AJAX, but kept running into a CORS error. The Capsule CRM guys have this turned off on their side so you cannot submit using AJAX with out running into this error.

After reaching out to them, I got this response:

> To do your requests using AJAX your website will need an additional
>   page that will process your webform POST on your site instead of
>   sending it directly to Capsule. This is sometimes called an AJAX
>   Proxy. This page just forwards the post onto the Capsule webform url
>   for processing, if you don't specify a "COMPLETE_URL" on your post the
>   form will return an HTTP 200 response instead of a redirect to make it
>   a bit easier for you to handle.

Having spent a significant portion of my time on the internet looking for an "AJAX proxy" I cannot seem to find an example and beginning to struggle to get it working. Hopefully some code will help with my question.

### form.html

```
<form id="contact-form" class="form">
  <label>Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="PERSON_NAME" placeholder="Name" value="" required/>
  <label>Email: </label>
  <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email" value="" required  /><br>
  <label>Telephone: </label>
  <input type="text" name="PHONE" placeholder="Telephone number" value="" required /><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<div class="result">
</div>
```

### form.js

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('.form').submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var messages = $('#result');
    var formData = $('.form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        url         : capsule.php,
        data        : formData
    })  
    .done(function(response) {
            console.log("Success: " + response);
        }
    })
    .error(function(response)   {
            console.log("Error: " + response);
        }
    });
});
```

### capsule.php

```
<?php
<form action="https://service.capsulecrm.com/service/newlead" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="FORM_ID" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <input type="text" name="FIRST_NAME" value="$_POST['PERSON_NAME']">
    <input type="text" name="LAST_NAME" value="$_POST['PERSON_NAME']">
    <input type="text" name="EMAIL" value="$_POST['PERSON_NAME']">
</form>
?>
```

I kind of almost need to do a double post. I need to post the data to the Capsule.php and then I need that to post. If that response is successful reverse it all and update the form.html without refreshing. Or does any one know how I should be forming the "AJAX proxy"?

This is my first solo delve into AJAX so please be gentle :).

## EDIT

After trying out the answer below and with the debugging on I have this back in the console in developer tools. It is difficult to debug as I don't have access to Capsules CRM server so I am currently also emailing them in regard to the problems I am having:

```
(
    [url] => https://service.capsulecrm.com/service/newlead
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 404
    [header_size] => 315
    [request_size] => 206
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.397695
    [namelookup_time] => 0.045858
    [connect_time] => 0.109964
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.268374
    [size_upload] => 705
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 1772
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 705
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.333441
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
```

Thank you all for your patience!

Comment: You've understood AJAX proxy concept improperly. `capsule.php` script shouldn't contain html form, it should receive AJAX request data from `form.html` and send/pass it to Capsule CRM page with POST request. This can be done by bunch of ways: CURL, `file_get_contents` and others..

Comment: Do you have any code examples? I am not sure what capsule will support in posting of the data? As long as it has those field names(PERSON_NAME, EMAIL etc.) it seems to work.

Comment: You've almost got it. [hindmost](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2118955/hindmost)'s comment and answer are good. The term proxy means any software that is acting as an intermediary for processing a request. In this scenario the intermediary is needed because you can't post the Ajax request directly. So there will be 2 posts exactly as you've described. The only other thing I can spot in your code is that in your JavaScript you will need quotes around the URL e.g. `url: 'capsule.php'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood AJAX proxy concept.

`capsule.php` script shouldn't contain form HTML, it should receive AJAX request data from `form.html` and send/pass it to Capsule CRM page by POST request. This can be done by bunch of ways: CURL, `file_get_contents()` and others.

Below is CURL implementation:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://service.capsulecrm.com/service/newlead',
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $_POST,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 200)
    return $response;
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found');
```

Comment: I have implemented this to the best of my ability (IE I have copied and pasted and moved all of the fields to the actual form that I require)

However when testing locally I get: 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:PATHTOFILE/capsule.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place. Any suggestions?

Comment: @KirisuteRanza AFAIU, you're loading your webpage as local file (by `file://` protocol) and this is the cause of the problem. AJAX requests don't work on local files. Your webpage should be accessible by http protocol. So you have to place it on web server

Comment: Ahhh ok, I think I was trying to be a bit premature on the testing. Will try it this evening when I can get access to my webserver. Thanks for your patience @hindmost

Comment: I have now managed to put it on my server. However, the line header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found'); is what I get back. (IE the console gives a 404 error. I changed this to a 403 and it said forbidden etc.) Anyway I possible way I could debug this?

Comment: @KirisuteRanza add this line `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));` to the script

Comment: Edited my original question with the problem I am now getting.

Comment: I have finished the implementation and it works like a charm. Many many many thanks to @hindmost and everyone else that was so patient! Capsule gave some support and the only aspect that was really missing was that the form data needed to be parsed again, it wouldn't accept just the ($_POST). 

So CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $_POST, needed to actually be http_build_query($f_POST). But without their guidance that would have been really difficult to figure out. 

Thanks again! :D

Comment: @KirisuteRanza - Would you be able to share the files you used that worked in the end re: this - I am looking to do exactly the same here... Thanks!